# Nodejs Cloud Vision Document Text Detection never returns

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

I am using Cloud Vision's OCR to extract text from PDF document but turns out that the result never returns for some PDF. These problematic PDF document ranges from 2-8 pages long, and are generally less than 2MB.

The OCR is executed upon a Cloud Function trigger, and upon successful conversion after the offline async operation, writes to Storage. I then listen for the OCR results in Storage using a `onFinalize` Storage trigger. The `onFinalize` never gets called.

```
function performTextDetection(id) {
    const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
    const bucketName = bucket.name;
    const fileName = `pdfs/${id}.pdf`
    const outputPrefix = 'ocr_results'
    const gcsSourceUri = `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName}`;
    const gcsDestinationUri = `gs://${bucketName}/${outputPrefix}/${id}/`;

    const inputConfig = {
        mimeType: 'application/pdf',
        gcsSource: {
            uri: gcsSourceUri,
        },
    };
    const outputConfig = {
        gcsDestination: {
            uri: gcsDestinationUri,
        },
    };
    const features = [{type: 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'}];
    const request = {
        requests: [
            {
            inputConfig: inputConfig,
            features: features,
            outputConfig: outputConfig,
            },
        ],
    };

    return client.asyncBatchAnnotateFiles(request)
    .then(([operation]) => {
        return operation.promise() //Waits too long and never completes
    })
}
```

This is the code that is triggered to execute the OCR but `operation.promise()` never completes and resulted in the function timeout. The wait is more than 6 minutes.

Also, the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) mentioned that it performs an offline async operation. How does one allow the operation to be completed offline, as the `operation.promise()` keeps the function running.

**UPDATE:**

This is how `performTextDetection` is called:

```
//Cloud function
module.exports = functions
.firestore
.document('pdf/{pdfId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    let item = snap.data()
    return adaptor.start(item)
})


//In the adaptor.js
function start(item) {
    let storagePath = `pdfs/${item.uid}.pdf`
    return savePdfToStorage(item, storagePath)
    .then((item) => {
        return performTextDetection(item.uid) //<== Called here
    })
}

function savePdfToStorage(pdf, storagePath) {
    return axios({
        method:'get',
        url: pdf.url,
        responseType:'stream'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return pipeToStorage(pdf, response, storagePath)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("axios error ", err);
    });
}

function pipeToStorage(pdf, response, storagePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gcFile = bucket.file(storagePath)

        response.data
        .pipe(gcFile.createWriteStream({
            metadata   : {
                contentType: "application/pdf"
            }
        }))
        .on('error', (error) => { 
            reject(error)
        })
        .on('finish', () => { 
            resolve(pdf)
        })
    }) 
}
```

The cloud vision version I am using is 1.11.0

Comment: Can you show how do you call this `performTextDetection`function?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec See edits

Comment: Which exact version of the @google-cloud/vision Node.js library are you using?

Comment: we are facing the same issue. our existing version which was working some hours before is now not working on same file it used to work.  Even https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#vision_text_detection_pdf_gcs-python is not working. Sometimes get an internal error from vision API in response.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have added in the edits. I'm using 1.11.0

Comment: @DeepakVerma Yes, turns out that the Cloud Vision does return, just that it returns HOURS later, like 5-8 hours later. And when it returns, some had `Internal Error`. This is the first time I am encountering in months...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Cloud Vision async method is fast again. Since you set up a onFinalize trigger to process the final result, it seems like you don't need to wait for the long running operation to finish. I'd recommend returning from the cloud function immediately after starting the async operation. operation.promise() just polls Cloud Vision to check whether the operation has finished.